# Video MP4 missing metadata

Tags: windows, video, metadata, mp4, properties

I can play the video just I don't have the metadata like video thumbnail or frame width length etc can't be seen win windows explorer and properties detail
Is there anyway to recover such MP4 to have thumbnail and etc easier. I have like 200 video so if there an app to auto recover all will be great help

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could post online one small video file, if you would like us to examine it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if these are *really* in MPEG-4 format, or rather *mislabeled* videos of another format, e.g., MKV. If so, you'd need to convert each to MP4 to see the metadata. Though I've never seen MPEG-4 files that did *not* show metadata, going through MP4 -> MP4 "conversion" should fix that, too.

There are many tools to batch-convert videos, such as [File Converter](https://file-converter.org/) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/freefileconvertcom/). However, test the effect of conversion on one or two files before doing them all. There are some tradeoffs between file *size* and *quality* in conversion. You may find the resultant files might be much larger than the original, or you can specify smaller, but lower-quality conversion output.

Comment: How to check if the file is mislabelled. I try to change extension manually like to mkv wmv avi mpeg but seems not working

Comment: Look at it's beginning bytes: https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html e.g., ��� ftypisom���isomiso2avc1mp41 or ���ftypmp42����isommp42